# What does "desying" mean in polarimetric radar studies?

Tags: radar

Do you see these two papers? [paper1](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291098-2760%2819970220%2914:3%3C191::AID-MOP17%3E3.0.CO;2-B/abstract)and [paper2](http://spie.org/Publications/Proceedings/Paper/10.1117/12.2180747)

It seems that `desying` has a special professional meaning in polarimetric radar studies.

I'm reading this [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5710415&filter%3DAND%28p_IS_Number%3A5770377%29) and somewhere it says:

> We present in this paper an improvement to a decomposition scheme using an idea of *desying* first conceived by Huynen.

I don't want to go through all the details and understand what `desying` means exactly. I don't read those two papers suggested in the beginning of this question. I just want to have an idea about `desying` so I decided to ask it from people who are mastered in radar studies.

Comment: Psi (Ψ) is used in some of the formulas for polarimetric radar as the symobol for an angle that represents the orientation between the target and the radar beam.  The 9 parameters that Huynen defines must be derived without Ψ, since they are meant to be used regardless of the orientation.  Removing the factor Ψ from the measured data is called desying.  Not posted as an answer, as I'm no radar guru and only know what a couple of minutes of googling found.

Comment: If you don't want to understand, why are you asking?

Comment: I do suggest you read the referenced papers, because Ψ seems to be central to a lot of what is going on.

Comment: Desying ought to really be spelled "deΨying" but who's gonna type THAT all the time?

Comment: @MattYoung I will follow your advise but I have read Huynen's dissertation. I just didn't think that `desying` has some kind of relationship with Psi($\Psi$)

Comment: @JRE could you tell me how do you write the greek symbol for Psi? And also do you mean the first two papers that I have linked in the question as referenced papers? I also googled before asking but google suggested `defying` instead of `desying`. I thought it should be a really hard professional word though

Comment: @JRE Could you please give me the link where you extracted the information mentioned in your first comment about `desying`. I wanna see if it has provided any references or pointed to a specific part of Huynen's dissertation? thanks alot

Comment: I cheated and copy/pasted the symbol Ψ from the wikipedia site.  Yes, I meant those.  But you'd probably do better to look up Huynen's book "Phenomenological theory of radar targets" in which he defines the term.

Comment: The info in my first comment came from "Target Scattering Decomposition in Terms
of Roll-Invariant Target Parameters" by Ridha Touzi (http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?reload=true&tp=&arnumber=4039635&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D4039635) page 76

Comment: And also the book `polarimetric radar imaging: From basics to applications` by `J.S.Lee` and `E.Pottier` pages 75 and 76 is a good reference. You can read these two pages of the book on google books @JRE

Comment: You can write $$\Psi$$ by typing \$\verb|$$\Psi$$|\$

Comment: Or `\$\Psi\$` for inline. EE.SE uses `\$` instead of just `$` because we are also often interested in talking about how much things cost.

Comment: The XML/HTML way using the entities &psi; and &Psi; will also work in most (not all, eg. not in comments) editable fields on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since no one else has answered, I'll go ahead and make an answer out of my comments.

Downvotes and corrections welcome. :)

---

Psi (Ψ) is used in some of the formulas for polarimetric radar as the symobol for an angle that represents the orientation between the target and the radar beam. The 9 parameters that Huynen defines must be derived without Ψ, since they are meant to be used regardless of the orientation. Removing the factor Ψ from the measured data is called desying.

Since Ψ is central to much of what goes on, I would suggest you read at least the relevant parts of the papers you linked to, or perhaps better yet find a copy of Huynen's book *Phenomenological Theory of Radar targets* in which he defines the term "desying."

The term "desying" makes more sense if you think of it as "deΨing" or "dePsiing."

My understanding of this comes from page 76 of [*Target Scattering Decomposition in Terms of Roll-Invariant Target Parameters* by Ridha Touzi.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4039635)